# Converting Messy Wolfram Code to Readable LaTeX: TemplateBox Troubles

Tags: wolfram-cloud, latex

I had a simple LaTeX expression written in the Wolfram Cloud, namely $a_0 = $. I used `ctrl+4` to display a box where I could write LaTeX. However, after some issue, it turned my simple expression into this mess:

```
Print[""!\*TemplateBox[<|\"boxes\" -> FormBox[RowBox[{SubscriptBox[StyleBox[\"a\", \"TI\"], \"0\"], \"\[LongEqual]\"}], TraditionalForm], \"errors\" -> {}, \"input\" -> \"a_0=\", \"state\" -> \"Boxes\"|>,\"TeXAssistantTemplate\"]""]
```

How can I revert it back to its original state without having to rewrite the entire code from scratch? Note that the expression $a_0=$ is just an example; we are talking about entire paragraphs that need correction. Therefore, I would like an automated way to convert the aforementioned mess back to a normal form.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
(* Given string *)
str = "\"!\*TemplateBox[<|\"boxes\" -> FormBox[RowBox[{SubscriptBox[StyleBox[\"a\", \"TI\"], \"0\"], \"\[LongEqual]\"}], TraditionalForm], \"errors\" -> {}, \"input\" -> \"a_0=\", \"state\" -> \"Boxes\"|>,\"TeXAssistantTemplate\"]\"";

(* Convert the string to an expression *)
expr = ToExpression[str, StandardForm, HoldForm];

(* Print the expression *)
Print[expr];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This means that I need to perform the actions you describe for each segment of the code that has been corrupted. This is equivalent to the task of rewriting it entirely. I was wondering if there is an option that could resolve the issue with a "click."